# Type Mismatch Error for using Array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function in VBA to return an array so I can assign that array to a combo box.

I am getting a very helpful Type Mismatch error.

```
Public Function ReturnActivePlayerList() As Variant

    Dim iPlayerCount As Integer
    iPlayerCount = ReturnPlayerCount()

    ReDim arrPlayerList(0 To iPlayerCount) As Long
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    iCounter = 0

    Sheets("MyPlayerDB").Range("A2").Activate

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

        arrPlayerList(iCounter) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        iCounter = iCounter + 1

    Loop

    ReturnActivePlayerList = arrPlayerList

End Function
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Where do you get the Error?

Comment: Hi, on this line here arrPlayerList(iCounter) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

Comment: what kind of Data is in the Coloum C?

Comment: You've got something in column C that can't be coerced to a number.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you Code and The Problem is Probably that the Datatype Of Column C does not match to the Type Long.

If you have a Float Number in this Column Take Double.

```
ReDim arrPlayerList(0 To iPlayerCount) As Double
```

If you have the Time in this Column take Date.

```
ReDim arrPlayerList(0 To iPlayerCount) As Date
```

Hope That can Help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for code clear and easily understandable:

```
Public Function ReturnActivePlayerList() As Variant

    Dim iPlayerCount, counter, row As Integer

    iPlayerCount = ReturnPlayerCount()

    'Define as Variant type
    ReDim arrPlayerList(0 To iPlayerCount) As Variant

    counter = 0

    'Set start row
    row = 2

    With Sheets("MyPlayerDB")

        'Loop until cell value is equal with ""
        Do While .Range("A" & row) <> ""

            'Set value from C column
            arrPlayerList(counter) = .Range("C" & row)

            'Increase counter
            counter = counter + 1

            'Increase row
            row = row + 1

        Loop

    End With

    ReturnActivePlayerList = arrPlayerList

End Function
```